# How to set UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to Set<Object> in java

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, unmodifiable

There is an Oauth2Authentication object that contains user-authority. When I want to get its authority and set it in authority of User object like this:

```
OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

LinkedHashMap linkedHashMap = (LinkedHashMap) oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();


user.setAuthorities((Set<GrantedAuthority>) oAuth2Authentication.getAuthorities());
```

the following exception is raised:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to
>   java.util.Set

How do I fix it?

Note:
The type of Authorities of User object is `Set<GrantedAuthority>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `oAuth2Authentication.getAuthorities()` is a `List`, you can easily create a `Set` from it:

```
user.setAuthorities(new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>(oAuth2Authentication.getAuthorities()));
```

Note that `GrantedAuthority` should have a proper implementation of `hashCode()` and `equals()` in order to be used as a member of a `HashSet`.